# Favorite Tag Colours

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

I'd like to see favorite tags get their own background colours on questions on the index page.

Currently, the big ol' list of questions comes up and displays a bunch of questions that correspond to your favorite tags by giving them a background colour.

What I wanna know is why are they all the same colour? Would it be massively inappropriate to colour the different tags differently based on which tag comes first in the relevant question?

So for instance, if you had two favorite tags, and they were ASP.NET and JQuery, if a question came up with both those tags, the first tag in the question would be the highlighted colour. If you had a question that was simply ASP.NET and whatever else, it'd be the ASP.NET colour. Same for JQuery, and all other tags.

If you have 20 favorited tags, this would make your homepage somewhat .. colourful. But then again, there would be a usable solution to that, like being able to reorder your favorite tags and then only colouring the top 5, the rest getting a default colour.

Am I the only person who thinks this would be useful?

Comment: Would this color really be useful? Or would it just add distracting visual noise?

Comment: Personally, if I could associate asp.net questions with the colour green and jquery questions with the colour red, that would help me enormously.

Comment: All the user's favorite tags should be purple. If not purple, atleast one uniform color, not different color for every tag. That would be visual noise.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Maybe make it an option. I could see it being useful, really. An option you can turn on to help you sort your tags on a page.

Comment: @Kendra Yeah, I was thinking the option would probably be much more useful than forcing it. Also allowing users to choose the colours they want would be cool.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion It's noise to you, not to me. Personally, my brain organises stuff a lot more quickly based on simple information like colour than by having to read the tags in every highlighted question.